# Unable to find reference to project in same solution VS 2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

Having upgraded VS2015 to SP1 my local project references in my solution could not be found. I set the project build order, rebuilt all the projects and also created a new solution but still bad references.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this by ensuring that the target .NET Framework for all the projects in the solution, that were referenced, were the same.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are running VS with administrator mode, then rebuild the entire solution.